# Adobe Air with sniffer Proxy?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, proxy, air, charles-proxy

I usually use Charles Proxy to catch requests/responses in browser. But now I develop Air application for mobile. Even if I run it on my PC Charles doesn`t catch requests of Air.

1) `Can I configure Charles Proxy to catch requests/responses outside of browser?`

If no:

2) `What tool do you use to sniff requests/responses outside of browser?`

I have both PC Windows 8 and Mac OS.

Comment: On Windows: Air uses the default Windows HTTP proxy if set, so you can set this in control panel (Internet Settings I think? I don't have a Win8 install to hand) to point to your Charles proxy instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your windows proxy settings to point to Charles. The default proxy settings to point to Charles should be 127.0.0.1 on 8888